# What does sed -i option do?

Tags: unix, sed, command-line

I'm debugging a shell script and trying to find out the task performed by the following command:

```
sed -i '1,+999d' /home/org_user/data.txt
```

I need to change this command as its failing with the following error:

```
illegal option sed -i
```

But before changing, I need to understand the BAU functioning.

Appreciate any inputs in this regard.

Comment: This command most likely uses GNU's implementation of the sed command. It can be replicated using most sed's using: `sed '1,1000d' file >temp_file && mv temp_file file`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your inputs and i agree with the command you're pointing out. But, can you please suggest what exactly '1,+999d' does here. I read the below answers and they suggest that it "should" delete the lines from 1 to 999. However, i want to be sure about it.

Comment: '1,+999d' in sed means from line 1 to 1+999 lines delete. The remaining file will be less the first 1000 lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will handle the scenario in a separate way since -i option is failing. Appreciate prompt response.. :)

Answer (score 147):

An applicable use of this is as follows. Say you have the following file `file.txt`:

```
1, 2, 6, 7, "p"
```

We want to replace "p" with 0.

```
sed 's/"p"/0/g' file.txt
```

Using the above simply prints the output into command line.

You'd think why not just redirect that text back into the file like this:

```
sed 's/"p"/0/g' file.txt > file.txt
```

Unfortunately because of [the nature of redirects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/16792) the above will simply produce a blank file.

Instead a temp file must be created for the output which later overwrites the original file something like this:

```
sed 's/"p"/0/g' file.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file.txt
```

Instead of doing the long workaround above sed edit in place option with -i allows for a much simpler command:

```
sed -i 's/"p"/0/g' file.txt
```

Comment: `sed -i 's/"p"/0/g' file.txt` returns with error_code `1` saying `sed: 1: "file.txt": invalid command code k` :(

Comment: This is likely BSD `sed`. You should specify "no address" here via `sed -i '' ' s/"p"/0/g' file.txt'`
see `man sed` for more information for your distribution

Answer (score 30):

If `-i` option given, `sed` edit files in place.

> ```
>    -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
>           edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
> ```

*from sed(1)*

http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Introduction

Comment: Philip Kirkbride's answer gives a helpful example which better explains what "edit files in place" actually _means_.

Answer (score 12):

Some implementations of `sed` do not support the `-i` option. What it does can be simulated by

```
sed -e '...' file > tmp
mv tmp file
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. So here, the '1,+999d' gives an error saying "garbled text" . Does this command delete all lines from the file ??

Comment: @Allzhere: It should delete the lines 1 to 999. I am not sure all seds support the `+`.

Comment: @choroba It deletes the lines 1 to 1+999=1000. It is also a GNU extension.

Comment: @Allzhere To delete all lines: `1,$d`.