# How to insert a string into a line in a file after a key word in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file with some lines.

Lines.txt

```
value1
value2
value3
```

And I would like to append the lines in the file into another file after a key word.

AnotherFile.txt

```
NotTheKeyWord SomeOtherStuff SomeOtherStuff
NotTheKeyWord THEKEYWORD SomeOtherStuff SomeOtherStuff
```

I think `sed` has what I need, but I am having issues figuring out how to insert the text into the middle of the line.

And I want the result of:

AnotherFile.txt

```
NotTheKeyWord SomeOtherStuff SomeOtherStuff
NotTheKeyWord THEKEYWORD value1 value2 value3 SomeOtherStuff SomeOtherStuff
```

Comment: I don't think that an "in file" replacement would work. You'll have to write the result to some temporary file and then write the content of the temporary file back to "AnotherFile.txt". Using  `sed` something like `sed -e s/THEKEYWORD/THEKEYWORD value1 value2 value3/` should work; now you have to think about how to create this command line from the content of the file "Lines.txt". Personally, I'd prefer writing some program in a "real" programming language if I were you.

Comment: Yeah, I would much prefer using a language I am more familiar with.
I don't have that option in this scenario... And my bash knowledge is rusty.

But I will try to look at it from a different angle like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) solution:

```sh
sed -r "s:(THEKEYWORD):\1 $(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' test.txt) :g" insert.txt
```

Where;

- `test.txt` is the value to be inserted, `$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' test.txt)` removes any newlines from the file, so it can be inserted on the **same** line
- `insert.txt` the text file where `THEKEYWORD` exists

---

If you wish to replace the file, use the [`-i`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527365/what-does-sed-i-option-do) option;

```sh
sed -i -r "s:(THEKEYWORD):\1 $(gsed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' test.txt) :g" insert.txt
```

---

As @KamilCuk pointed out, using `paste -sd ' ' test.txt` could be used to remove the newlines, and insert the file;

```sh
sed -r "s:(THEKEYWORD):\1 $(paste -sd ' ' test.txt) :g" insert.txt
```

---

[Terminal output + sed version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjPKA.png)

Comment: `gsed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` +1, but you can just `paste -sd ' '`